# MySQL joining data from 2 tables based on foreign key in a third, without duplicates or group by

Tags: mysql, select, join, key

I have three tables that look like this:

```
People:
+------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| fname      | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| lname      | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| dob        | date        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00        |                |
| license_no | varchar(24) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| date_added | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| status     | varchar(8)  | NO   |     | Allow             |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+

Units:
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| number   | varchar(3)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| resident | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| type     | varchar(16) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

Visits:
+----------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field    | Type      | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+----------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| vis_id   | int(11)   | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| unit     | int(11)   | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| time_in  | timestamp | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   |                |
| time_out | timestamp | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
+----------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

There are multiple foreign keys linking these tables:

```
units.resident -> people.id

visits.unit    -> units.id

visits.vis_id  -> people.id
```

I am able to run this query to find all *residents* ie - everyone from `people` that are referenced by the `units.resident` foreign key:

```
SELECT  concat(p.lname, ', ', p.fname) as 'Resident', p.dob as 'Birthday', 
u.number as 'Unit #' 
from people p, units u
where p.id = u.resident
order by u.number
```

It returns the results I want... However, it'd be useful to do the *opposite* of this to find all the people who *are not* residents ie- everyone from `people` who aren't referenced by the `units.resident` foreign key.

I've tried many different queries, most notably some inner and left joins, but I'm getting waaaaay too many duplicate entries (from what I've read here, this is normal). The only thing I've found that works is using a `group by license_no`, because as of now the "residents" don't have this information, like this:

```
SELECT  p.id, concat(p.lname, ', ', p.fname) as 'Visitor',
p.license_no as 'License', u.number from people p
left join units u on u.number <> p.id
group by p.license_no order by p.id;
```

This works for all but *one* resident, who's `u.number` is displayed on ALL results. The residents will soon have `license_no` entries, and I can't have that one odd entry in the returned results all the time, so this query won't work as a long-term solution.

How can I structure a query *without* a `group by` that will return the results I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
SELECT 
 p.id
 , P.fname
 , P.lname
FROM
 people AS p
LEFT JOIN
 units AS u
ON
 p.id = u.resident 
WHERE
 u.resident IS NULL
```

Extra hint.

Table people should be called person.
By u.resident you mean a person.   so it should be a person_id there in the unit table...

Better logic helps to write SQL better, if your name convention is clear to use.

Comment: Thank you! Performance-wise it seems a _very_ small bit faster, but as this scales up I guess that will be useful. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a NOT EXISTS clause to exclude those people who are residents.

```
SELECT  P.id
        ,P.fname
        ,P.lname
        ,etc...
FROM    People P
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Units U WHERE U.resident = P.id)
```

Comment: Looks like that was exactly what I needed, thank you! I guess I was making it too complex... Can you tell me what the `SELECT 1` does? Is that like `DISTINCT`?

Comment: Not use a NOT EXISTS... Correlated subquerys are very bad for performance in MySQL. you should use a LEFT JOIN with a WHERE ... IS NULL to get a better query

Comment: @RaymondN : so how would I structure that then? I guess I don't understand what I would be comparing to `NULL`... `u.resident`?

Comment: The `EXISTS` statement checks that the statement that follows it returns something. It does need ato check for a specif value. I use `SELECT 1` which returns the value 1 which is something. It would be equally valide to do `SELECT id FROM ...` or `SELECT resident FROM ...` or even `SELECT * FROM ...` (but that last one is fround upon in this establishment.